# Someone can trace this crashdump for me?

Tags: crash-dumps

I cannot make up the crash cause out of the following crash dump, someone that has the skills to determine the problem, could try that?

These Windows 8.1 crashes seems to have started after installing symbols (pdb) & debugging packages. It could also have a different origin, hardware failure or else. I however cannot make up the logic myself.

Dump trace: [Dump debugger output](http://pastebin.com/BipHZRY5)

Answer (score 0):

Bugcheck 0x109 is CRITICAL_STRUCTURE_CORRUPTION. I would not suspect Symbols and Debugging packages, except you did some kernel debugging during that time (but then you would probably know how to interpret the output yourself).

I saw `fairplaykd.sys` in the list of drivers. It comes with Multi Theft Auto. And I saw this Twitter message from 25th of February:

> Update: Problems with MTA:SA 1.3.5 and Windows 8/8.1 32bit should be resolved now. Redownload the MTA installer from http://tinyurl.com/pmy732g

Maybe you give that latest Update a try.